# postgresql vs mysql in ease of scaling, and usefulness for highly relational (tons of foreign keys) databases

Tags: mysql, postgresql, foreign-keys, scaling

OK, I've read quite a few things about PostgresSQL and it seems to have a few features which seem pretty awesome, I really like the idea of being able to update a table and adding a column/index without having to wait for the database and have it being locked. Also it seems to be about as fast as MySQL, when it comes to the performance. But I'm mostly worried about the ease of scaling it up with as relational as my system is.

Right now I have tables which all have foreign keys and relate to eachother for ease of use, and I use foreign keys *a lot*. For an example of this, I've got a "players" table which then has many tables which relate out of it. I have the following tables that branch out of it.

1. players_mail
2. players_mail_attachments
3. players_bank
4. players_inventory
5. players_effects
6. players_effects_temp
7. players_quests
8. players_quests_tasks
9. ...

and the list continues on. I have a few other tables and they all use the players table's id as one of their indexes and relate back to the players.id column. Also the mail one has a foreign key to the mail, and others are also as relational. Does PostgreSQL scale well with that relational of a database? I also have a few indexes on most of the tables. All tables that aren't "root" tables(like the players one) have two indexes the primary key and then also the indexes for the foreign keys.

I've already read that postgres doesn't automatically create indexes on foreign keys, so I know that I'll likely have to manually create those indexes. With what I've said how well does Postgres handle that kind of dataset? I'm sure that someone else out there has already created a highly relational database in a RDBMS before me, and I'd love to hear their experience.

Edit to add:

I primarily am looking at it because how it handles locking during writes, and also because I don't know how I feel about oracle, and being reliant on xtradb as a database format. Even though I know that MariaDB is working on it's own database format, I still don't like my favorite database format being under the control of a company who might just kill it, or worse make it completely closed source. After I go through postgresql and look at how I can easily move my databases to it and look over the tools for it, I'll pick which answer was best, I'll also leave it open for 24hrs so that people can amend anything that they wish.

edit 2:

I've just finally really started looking at the database format itself, and whilst I really like some of the things I cannot stand Object Orientation, it drives me insane. I was fully ready to go to postgres until I realized that it's modeled after half of object orientation, I guess one of my last bits of questions for this is, it doesn't force me to use classes and objects correct? Wikipedia says that it's a "bridge" between the OOP and RDMBs, thus I take it as I can still do everything the way that I like to think of it. If that is how it works, then I'll likely love the database, if I cannot then I'll hate it. And I'd rather not hate a tool that is so crucial to the success of this thing.

Comment: You don't need to "worry" about the O part of ORDBMS. You can use PostgreSQL like any relational database - indeed, that's what the vast majority of deployments do. You can then *also* use the object-relational stuff *if you want to*, but it's in no way mandatory.

Comment: Ah OK that's good to know. I like relational way of thinking about things. I'm probably going to go to Postgres then since I'll be safe in knowing that no big company owning it especially oracle. Even with that fork, as in mariadb, I don't trust them to not harm me later on.

Comment: I thought I should just add a comment here. After trying to setup postgres, and then using the PHPPgAdmin tool, the entire thing is backwards. Weird and strange. No user setup as installation, no info on how to do it. I had to google to get anything. MySQL at least works logically. I like things that work with some level of sense. I want to use Postgres, but everything... i mean everything... is not set up logically. Mysql is weird but it's consistent. Postgres is haphazardly put together and I'm goign to stick with mariadb and go to aria if I have to. Not going to use Postgres.

Comment: Don't judge the DBMS-engine by the PHPpgAdmin-tool. (I prefer *not* using the tools, except maybe for browsing) For serious DBA-work, just stick to the commandline and your favorite editor.

Comment: the command line. I said the command line too. I looked at the PHPPgAdmin tool as a last resort. I prefer command line for everything but visualizing my datasets. It was awful. Nothing was setup logically and I had to jump through hoops to get it setup. I fear that the rest of my experience would be the same.

Comment: That's obviously something taht differs between people. I've personally found MySQL extremely inconsistent whenever I've had to work with it, and I find PostgreSQL very much more logic and definitely a lot more consistent. It's obviously not consistent with whatever MySQL does, though, so someone experienced with MySQL might be confused. My experience is that people coming from any other database than MySQL find it pretty logical. (Again, talking about PostgreSQL here - I don't use phppgadmin, so I can't comment on that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

300 tables with lots of foreign keys and indexes, about 150 tables having more than 1000 records, about 20 tables having more than 100000 records is big enough for you?

Never faced performance issues caused by the PostgreSQl itself. Monstrous 400+ lines queries with about 15 subselectes runs within a second.

To sum up: PostgreSQL scales very well. No match for Oracle of course, but it gets the job done. The only hint: if you are **VERY** concerned about performance  - replace triggers with rules and use views instead of stored procedures if possible

Comment: +1 for Postgre, and related to scaling, the new Cloud tools seem interesting: http://www.enterprisedb.com/solutions/postgres-plus-cloud-computing

Comment: Ah well I don't know I might end up going with it because I found out how it does locking, and thus I found it to be really interesting and it'll likely help out with things.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really worried about scaling out, then eventually you should stop relying on foreign keys within the database and handle it at the application level.

As far as scaling MySQL vs Postgres, you're mostly going to run into the same hurdles since they're both really fast and stable RDBMS.

All that said, Postgres is much more ACID compliant than MySQL, it handles FKs just as you're needing and I would generally recommend it based on what you've expressed in your post.

Comment: Handling foreign keys (or other constraints that can be expressed with SQL) in the application is a very bad idea. If your data is important youn will have more than one application accessing the data. And the data will live a lot longer than any of the applications that access it. Managing the integrity rules very quickly becomes a nightmare then. I can't count the times where I had to clean up the database even though the application developers guaranteed that everything will be handled properly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's for a game that I've been writing, and thus it'll be handled by that game per server. The data itself will mostly just be used for that. And thus I don't get what you're talking about.

Comment: @133794m3r: my comment was for jturmel's statement "stop relying on foreign keys". Relying on the application to make sure all constraints are maintained is calling for trouble.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if you're really looking at scaling, relying on the RDBMS to handle your constraints is quickly going to become a bottle neck, since he mentioned scaling, I brought that up. At that point you probably shouldn't be using an RDBMS anymore, but that's not the point of this thread.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah ok. I was wondering what you were talking about. jturmel and yeah I know that that is going to be one of the big things I"m going to have to do down the road. Same reason why most people eventually go NoSQL when forced to. I was just wondering about general scaling. And I don't know which one I'm going to mark as answered. I think I"m going to go with john's one since it was slightly more there. I have no idea why but I feel like it's the one, since I want to mark one of them. I wish I could mark both but I cannot and that one takes the cake this time.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what you use. Everything depends on the application and architecture. For example, foreign keys does not hurt much if you make a little redundancy.
example:

```
players(id, ....)
players_quests(id, player_id, ....)
players_quests_tasks(id,player_quest_id, ...)
```

To find players_quests_tasks belongs to some player you need joins.
Solution: add player_id to players_quests_tasks table.
It's break normalization but there is no join:

```
players_quests_tasks(id,player_quest_id, player_id,...)
SELECT * FROM players_quests_tasks WHERE player_id=:player_id_to_find;
```

It's make sense if you have much more reads than writes.

Comment: I've already done that but I do joins to get said data right now and they all do that as far as their designs go. It's simple it's relational. It's all players_id_* and such and that's why they have the names as they do.